# How to make a download to dialogbox

Tags: vb.net, download, dialog

I have a file that can be saved to a portable device. I would like to know how I could create a `DialogBox` to select a portable device to save my file to. This is very similar to a save, as `DialogBox` except the file already exists.

Perhaps better said, I need to be able to download to a `DialogBox`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [FileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx) class to display two [FileDialogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx). First, have the user select the file to copy. Next, have the user select the location where the file is to be copied (e.g. portable USB thumb drive).

Comment: @john: You can select multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

"Download to a dialog box" makes little sense.  There is no reason why a SaveFileDialog couldn't do the job.  If you like to encourage the user to pick a removable drive as the save location then assign the SaveFileDialog.InitialDirectory property.  You can find out what drives are removable by using the System.IO.DriveInfo class.  Its DriveType property tells you what kind of drive it is.